# c code output unexpected/expected behaviour

Tags: c

what is wrong with this code ? can anyone explain ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
  int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

  int main()
  {
      int num;
      int d;
      int size = TOTAL_ELEMENTS -2;
      printf("%d\n",(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2));

      for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
          printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

      return 0;
  }
```

when i print it gives 5, but inside for loop what is happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator returns a value of type `size_t`, which is an *unsigned* value. In your `for` loop condition test:

```
d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)
```

you are comparing a *signed* value (`d`) with an *unsigned* value (`TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2`). This is usually a warning condition, and you should turn up the warning level on your compiler so you'll properly get a warning message.

The compiler can only generate code for either a signed or an unsigned comparison, and in this case the comparison is unsigned. The integer value in `d` is converted to an unsigned value, which on a 2's complement architecture ends up being `0xFFFFFFFF` or similar. This is not less than your `TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2` value, so the comparison is false.

Comment: 2s complement is irrevelant - `(size_t)-1` is always `SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score -1):

You're starting the loop by setting d = -1, it should be d = 0. So for the first element you're reading random bits of memory.

If you fix that, then you can change your printf to be

```
printf("%d\n",array[d]);
```

As you've also marked this as homework, I'd advise also take a look at your loop terminating condition.

Comment: but array[d+1] gets printed, so what's wrong ? this is not reading random bits, since loop terminates immediately

Comment: i didn't, but see above explanation by Greg